# Repeated convergence test failure reason in this particular problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, warning-messages, nonlinear

I have the following Mathematica Code to solve a coupled system of ODEs, which in principle is correct and its context is not a priori important:

```
(*auxiliar definitions*)
ρ[t] = Λ*a[t]^(-3*(1 + w))
p[t] = w*ρ[t]

(*equations*)
Ec1 = a[t]^4*b[t]^6*ρ[t] - 6 γ*a[t]^2*b[t]^4*(a'[t])^2 + 
  36*(3 α - β)*b[t]^2*(a'[t])^4 - 
  24 (3 α - β)*a[t]*b[t]^2*(a'[t])^2*a''[t] + 
  12*(3 α - β)*a[t]^2*b[t]^2*(a''[t])^2 - 
  24*(3 α - β)*a[t]^2*b[t]^2*a'[t]*a'''[t] - 
  60*(3 α - β)*a[t]^2*(a'[t])^2*(b'[t])^2 + 
  24*(3 α - β)*a[t]^2*b[t]*(a'[t])^2*b''[t] + 
  24*((3 α - β)*a[t]*b[t]*(a'[t])^3 + 
     2*(3 α - β)*a[t]^2*b[t]*a'[t]*a''[t])*b'[t]

Ec2 = a[t]^4*b[t]^7*p[t] + 2*γ*a[t]^2 b[t]^5*(a'[t])^2 + 
  12 (3 α - β)*b[t]^3 a'[t]^4 + 
  12 (3 α - β)*a[t]^2*b[t]^3*(a''[t])^2 + 
  16 (3 α - β)*a[t]^2*b[t]^3*a'[t]*a'''[t] + 
  8 (3 α - β)*a[t]^3*b[t]^3*a''''[t] - 
  120 (3 α - β)*a[t]^3*a'[t]*(b'[t])^3 - 
  8 (3 α - β)*a[t]^3*b[t]^2*a'[t]*b'''[t] + 
  60 ((3 α - β)*a[t]^2 b[t]*(a'[t])^2 + 
     2 (3 α - β)*a[t]^3 b[t]*a''[t]) b'[t]^2 + 
  4 (γ*a[t]^3 b[t]^5 - 
     12 (3 α - β)*a[t]*b[t]^3*(a'[t]^2)) a''[t] - 
  4 (γ*a[t]^3 b[t]^4 a'[t] - 
     12 (3 α - β)*a[t]*b[t]^2*a'[t]^3 + 
     18 (3 α - β)*a[t]^2*b[t]^2 a'[t] a''[t] + 
     12 (3 α - β)*a[t]^3*b[t]^2 a'''[t]) b'[t] - 
  16 ((3 α - β)*a[t]^2*b[t]^2*(a'[t])^2 + 
     2 (3 α - β)*a[t]^3*b[t]^2*a''[t] - 
     5 (3 α - β)*a[t]^3*b[t]*a'[t]*b'[t]) b''[t]

(*initial conditions*)

ic1 = 1; 
ic2 = 2/10; 
ic3 = 1/10; 
ic4 = 1; 
ic5 = 1/10; 
ic6 = 2/10; 
ic = {a[1] == ic1, a'[1] == ic2, a''[1] == ic3, b[1] == ic4, b'[1] == ic5, b''[1] == ic6, a'''[1] == 
   1/(24 ic2 ic4^2 (3 α - β))
     ic1^(-2 - 
     3 w) (108 ic1^(3 w) ic2^4 ic4^2 α - 
      72 ic1^(1 + 3 w) ic2^2 ic3 ic4^2 α + 
      36 ic1^(2 + 3 w) ic3^2 ic4^2 α + 
      72 ic1^(1 + 3 w) ic2^3 ic4 ic5 α + 
      144 ic1^(2 + 3 w) ic2 ic3 ic4 ic5 α - 
      180 ic1^(2 + 3 w) ic2^2 ic5^2 α + 
      72 ic1^(2 + 3 w) ic2^2 ic4 ic6 α - 
      36 ic1^(3 w) ic2^4 ic4^2 β + 
      24 ic1^(1 + 3 w) ic2^2 ic3 ic4^2 β - 
      12 ic1^(2 + 3 w) ic3^2 ic4^2 β - 
      24 ic1^(1 + 3 w) ic2^3 ic4 ic5 β - 
      48 ic1^(2 + 3 w) ic2 ic3 ic4 ic5 β + 
      60 ic1^(2 + 3 w) ic2^2 ic5^2 β - 
      24 ic1^(2 + 3 w) ic2^2 ic4 ic6 β - 
      6 ic1^(2 + 3 w) ic2^2 ic4^4 γ + 
      ic1 ic4^6 Λ)};

(*parameters*)
w = -1; Λ = 20;
α = 3; β = 2; γ = 1;

(*solution*)
s = NDSolve[{Ec1 == 0, Ec2 == 0, ic}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]

Plot[Evaluate[{a[t], b[t]} /. s], {t, -0.1, 20}]
```

Although the program gives a reasonable solution to plot, the output also gives this error message:

```
NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t == 1.`; unable to continue.

InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-0.0995894} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
```

Why is this so? Can it be solved? It is a problem of the ODE system?

Comment: Your code does not contain the definitions of `Ec00` and `Ecii`. Are those supposed to be `Ec1` and `Ec2`? If so, I obtain a different warning: "Zero pivot was detected during the numerical factorization or there was a problem in the iterative refinement process. It is possible that the matrix is ill-conditioned or singular."

Comment: Because of `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` (and maybe because you have to use it because the system is a DAE), the solver used is [IDA](https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/ida), the only implicit solver available in Mathematica. See also the tech note [IDA Method for NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveIDAMethod.html). Sometimes you can differentiate the DAE to get an ODE in explicit form. Sometimes you can put your diff. eq. system in explicit form by hand, even though `NDSolve` cannot. Then you can use a different `Method`.

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry, there was a typo, now it is corrected, you are right. I don't get that warning message, that's kind of weird. Does it show any solution?

Comment: @MichaelE2 The problem is that if I change the Method, the warning now is that the system can't be solved as a DAE. Is there any other method that should work better? Or I should just try more of them and check it?

Comment: There is one degree of freedom in the initial condition: `{Ec1, Ec2} /. t -> 1 /. Solve[ic]`. This is why there is a convergence problem (`ndcf`) at the initial condition. There are infinitely many solutions. Further, the highest order derivatives of `a` and `b` appear in one equation and are absent in the other. Differentiating the deficient-order ODE yields a system that has deficient rank: `Det@Last@CoefficientArrays[{D[Ec1, t], Ec2}, {b'''[t], a''''[t]}]` --> `0`. Even if the initial condition is solved, you're likely to continue to have convergence problems. Perhaps a mistake in the ODEs?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for the comment, all you said is very interesting, but I have some serious doubts there. The additional degree of freedom shouldn't be a problem, since I can add reasonable initial values for `a''', b'''` or `a''''`. And yeah, it seems that the higher derivatives are not determined by the lower ones, but differentiating the lower derivative one doesn't help as far as I have checked (what's the meaning of de deficient rank you said? I don't undersand it). The dramatic thing is that the ODEs are correct... does this mean that the system has no solution? I'm kinda desperate

Comment: `{D[Ec1, t], Ec2}` has the linear form $$\eqalign{
A\,a^{(4)} + B\,b^{(3)} &= P \cr
C\,a^{(4)} + D\,b^{(3)} &= Q \cr
}$$ with det = $AD-BC=0$ and the coefficients $A,B,C,D,P,Q$ free of $a^{(4)}$ and $b^{(3)}$. So the system cannot be solved for $a^{(4)}$ and $b^{(3)}$. In fact the system has either infinitely many solutions for $a^{(4)}$ and $b^{(3)}$ or no solutions. I don't recall having come across a system with such a feature, so it's okay to doubt what I said earlier. However, solving the system is just algebra. If $a^{(4)}$ and $b^{(3)}$ cannot be uniquely determined, it sounds bad.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, that sounds terrible. Of course, solving the system is pure algebra but I have not been able to do it even numerically: in fact, the solution plotted by mathematica i don't think it's reliable even though it looks decent. If only there was a way to obtain a reliable solution then everything would be more clear, but I don't know a way to do it. Thank you very much for your explanation, it was elementary but I didn't get it at the first time. I don't know if $a^{(4)}$ and $b^{(3)}$ can be uniquely determined, but the truth is that the only information are these two equations...

Comment: @MichaelE2 There's a curious thing, because if one lets the system as it is (without deriving the lower order equation) and tells Mathematica to `Det@Last@CoefficientArrays[{Ec1, Ec2}, {b''[t], a''''[t]}]` for the highest derivatives in every equation, the determinant then is not 0, so it should have a unique solution: am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147212/discussion-between-michael-e2-and-axionlike-particles).